# Muxing AVPackets into mp4 file - revisited

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm refering to this thread here:
[Muxing AVPackets into mp4 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679833/muxing-avpackets-into-mp4-file?rq=1)

The question over there is mainly the same that I have and the first answer looks very promising.
The source (somkind of pseudo) code that the user *pogorskiy* provides seems to do exactly what I need:

```
AVOutputFormat * outFmt = av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL);
AVFormatContext *outFmtCtx = NULL;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFmtCtx, outFmt, NULL, NULL);
AVStream * outStrm = av_new_stream(outFmtCtx, 0);

AVCodec * codec = NULL;
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(outStrm->codec, codec);
outStrm->codec->coder_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;

///....
/// set some required value, such as
/// outStrm->codec->flags
/// outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio
/// outStrm->disposition
/// outStrm->codec->codec_tag
/// outStrm->codec->bits_per_raw_sample
/// outStrm->codec->chroma_sample_location
/// outStrm->codec->codec_id
/// outStrm->codec->codec_tag
/// outStrm->codec->time_base
/// outStrm->codec->extradata 
/// outStrm->codec->extradata_size
/// outStrm->codec->pix_fmt
/// outStrm->codec->width
/// outStrm->codec->height
/// outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio
/// see ffmpeg.c for details  

avio_open(&outFmtCtx->pb, outputFileName, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

avformat_write_header(outFmtCtx, NULL);

for (...)
{
av_write_frame(outFmtCtx, &pkt);
}

av_write_trailer(outFmtCtx);
avio_close(outFmtCtx->pb);
avformat_free_context(outFmtCtx);
```

The *pkt* data, I receive from a third party API from my connectec camera. There is no file to open, to read the input data from and there is no RTSP stream to be received from the camera. It is just an API call, that gives me the pointer to a H264 encoded frame which is exactly the raw data for an AVPacket.

Anyway, I try to use this code as base for my applicatio, but the first problem that occurs is, that I get a runtime error:

```
Could not find tag for codec none in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
```

So I started adding some more information to the codec, as *pogorskiy* suggested:

```
outStrm->codec->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
outStrm->codec->width = 1920;
outStrm->codec->height = 1080;
```

Now that I provided a codec_id, I was hoping, that the runtime message changes to at least something different, but it still ist the same:

```
Could not find tag for codec none in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
```

Any idea on how I can set up the structures, so that I can open an mp4 file for writing my packets to?

Comment: Oh, btw, I had to modify the above code according to the information I found here: http://sgros.blogspot.com/2013/01/deprecated-functions-in-ffmpeg-library.html
Meaning `AVStream * outStrm = av_new_stream(outFmtCtx, 0);` is now `AVStream * outStrm = avformat_new_stream(outFmtCtx, NULL); outStrm->id = 0;`

Comment: It seems as if I ask my ffmpeg/libav questions very unspecific because I do not get any replies (also the last two of them were not very much given an answer). I have to admit, that the libav lib is a beast and it therefore is quiet hard fpr me to even ask the right question for the things I'd like to achieve. Maybe somebody could point out what is so hard to understand in my questions, so that I can improve my asking style.

Comment: However, I got it working by myself (again). At least the thing that answeres specifically my question, meaning how to open an mp4 file with the above mentioned method and write my video packets to it (see answer below).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it working. At least I can open an mp4 file and write my H264 encoded packets to it. The file even opens in VLC and shows the very first frame... Nothing more, but it is a start.

So I place the code her, in order to show this minimal solution. I still am very happy if somebody would give his/hers opinion on it, because it still does not work perfectly...

```
char outputFileName[] = "camera.mp4";

av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);

AVOutputFormat * outFmt = av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL);
AVFormatContext *outFmtCtx = NULL;
avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outFmtCtx, outFmt, NULL, NULL);
AVStream * outStrm = avformat_new_stream(outFmtCtx, NULL);
outStrm->id = 0;
outStrm->time_base = {1, 30};
outStrm->avg_frame_rate = {1, 30};

AVCodec * codec = NULL;
avcodec_get_context_defaults3(outStrm->codec, codec);

outFmtCtx->video_codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;

///....
/// set some required value, such as
/// outStrm->codec->flags
/// outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio
/// outStrm->disposition
/// outStrm->codec->codec_tag
/// outStrm->codec->bits_per_raw_sample
/// outStrm->codec->chroma_sample_location
outStrm->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
outStrm->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
/// outStrm->codec->time_base
/// outStrm->codec->extradata 
/// outStrm->codec->extradata_size
/// outStrm->codec->pix_fmt
outStrm->codecpar->width = 1920;
outStrm->codecpar->height = 1080;
/// outStrm->codec->sample_aspect_ratio
/// see ffmpeg.c for details  

avio_open(&outFmtCtx->pb, outputFileName, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);

avformat_write_header(outFmtCtx, NULL); 

*** Camera access loop via GenICam API starts here ***
n++;
av_init_packet(&avPacket);
avPacket.data = static_cast<uint8_t*>(pPtr); // raw data from the Camera with H264 encoded frame
avPacket.size = datasize; // datasize received from the GenICam API along with pPtr (the raw data)
avPacket.pts = (1/30) * n; // stupid try to set pts and dts somehow... Working on this...
avPacket.dts = (1/30) * (n-1);
avPacket.pos = n;
avPacket.stream_index = outStrm->index;

av_write_frame(outFmtCtx, &avPacket);

**** Camera access loop ends here ****

av_write_trailer(outFmtCtx);
avio_close(outFmtCtx->pb);
avformat_free_context(outFmtCtx);
```

As I said, the resulting mp4 file shows the very first frame for a split second and after that it stops playing.
I think the first frame is displayed, because I make sure that this is an I-frame, containing the complete image.

I don't know if I have to provide some additional data to the muxer in order to get a working mp4 file. I'm still working on this.

Any comments and ideas are highly welcome!

Thanks,
Maik

Comment: `avPacket.pts = (1/30) * n` --> pts/dts are signed *integers*. All your calculated values get cast to floor(value). Since your timebase is 1/30. Just set it to `n`.

Comment: its obviously correct what you are saying. What a stupid mistake I made there. However, it still does not display any dts time in MediaInfo.
The mp4 file is containg all my packet data, but since there seems to be an issue with the timing, it says in the header, the file is 40ms long. By opening it in VLC, it still does only show the very first frame and then stops.